# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry Foo.class

Tags: android, gradle

Got this well known exception while building the project.

My question is:
**How can I found where (in what jars, libraries) duplicates of `Foo.class` are?**

I used to solve such a problem in past, usually the reason was in different versions of Android libs (support, play, so on...). There are 10 modules in my project, so each time I need to compare all the dependencies in 10 `build.gradle`.

Particularly, now it's `javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class`. And I stuck, can't find any duplicated dependencies.
So I need just a simple way to know - which library X contains `Foo.class` and which another  library Y contains `Foo.class`. Is it possible?

Comment: Umm. That depends on the **actual value** of `Foo`, Show your Gradle file and the stacktrace

Comment: Guess: `com.google.gms.Foo`, and you've duplicated some Google Play Services

Comment: What are you compiling that has `javax.*`? Have you tried `gradlew app:dependencies` from the project directory?

Comment: share your gradle file.....!!!

Comment: I use `javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0` , it's needed by dagger. `gradlew app:dependencies` shows a lot of this lib deps, but of the same version - 1.0.

Comment: I have already faced this problem. Just change your class path

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `build.gradle`

```
task findDuplicates  {
    doLast {
        def pathMap = [:]
        def jars = configurations.runtime.asFileTree.matching {
            include '*.jar'
        }
        jars.visit { FileVisitDetails fvd ->
            FileTree classTree = zipTree(fvd.file).matching {
                include '**/*.class'
            }
            classTree.visit { FileVisitDetails fvd2 ->
                String path = fvd2.relativePath.pathString
                List<String> jarList = pathMap[path]
                if (!jarList) {
                    jarList = []
                    pathMap[path] = jarList
                }
                jarList << fvd.file.name
            }
        }
        pathMap.each { path, jarList ->
            if (jarList.size() > 1) {
                println "Duplicate $path at $jarList" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then call `gradle findDuplicates` from the command line